# Magento 2: Product status doesn't change after changing to another status

Tags: magento2, products, admin-panel

When I changed the status of the product from visible to invisible and when I view the product (in the admin panel) it displays correctly but on the table shows the preview status (see attached ). and it doesn't work correctly on the frontend.
Can everybody help me  ?
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run re-indexing and clear cache